# WordPress Post Updating is Not Working

Tags: posts, updates

I have an issue with My Website WordPress Post Updating is Not Working, When I tried to update the post it updated the post. Kindly Give your professional guidance Please

Comment: Welcome! You’ll need to be a lot more specific before anyone can provide an answer. Where are you updating the post? Are you sure you’re checking the right page/post for updates? Are you using a caching plugin? Are there any errors in your `WP_DEBUG` log? Please use the “edit” button on your question and update with more information.